# bootstrap and google app engine

Tags: javascript, css, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

I have got some experiance in python, html and php and databases(most SQL Server), and im trying to get into google app engine and bootstraps.

after reading some guides about it, and playing with some examples (guestbook and task list), Im completly in the dark with this problem:

http://bit.ly/1hCEZW1
this is a simple layout i created using layoutit website. . in the future i want to use some of its component to upgrade my GuestBook  (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python), but right now i only want to deploy this layout to appengine, how should edit the app.yaml file?
this what i thought should work:

application: obp-lo
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /bootstrap
  static_dir: bootstrap
- url: /css
  mime_type: text/css
  static_dir: css
- url: /js
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_dir: js
- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

but it doesn't :(.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't bootstrap files just .css and .js files? So they are static files and should go under your static folder

eg, your app.yaml file could have this entry

```
- url: /static
    static_dir: static
```

and you can have all your css inside `/static/css/` and all your js inside `/static/js/`

But they should not go under the same directory as the Guestbook because it was not marked as static.